# Correct workflow for cloth modelling

Tags: modeling

What is the correct workflow for cloth modelling? I've been trying to create pants that contain pockets and zippers and the like but the result is always terrible. And surprisingly there is nothing on youtube or anywhere else for that matter about this matter. Everyone just uses Marvelous Designer and Zbrush.

The goal here is realism.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Garment Tool]

I can recommend an add-on called Garment Tool. I usually make the parts in Illustrator and import them as SVGs. This can be done in Blender, too with Beziers. I just find Illustrator's tools more convenient

[Youtube Demo of how to use Garment Tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvdxE6YbOSU&lc=z22zexxbtzehglif4acdp43bif3c0tpch54z5awnd5xw03c010c.1551581580632292)

So, you model the pieces of your clothing in 2D, like you would cut pieces of cloth. Then you place them near the model where you want them to go and the add-on creates the connections between the pieces with "Seams". It then puts a cloth simulation on the triangulated pieces and projects them onto your model. The results are really good!